# My app doesn't work when facebook app is installed in my device

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on

I create an application that it shared an post on facebook with easyfacebook. If I unistalled the official facebook app from my device I can share the post and It works, but when I installed facebook app my application don't share anything...Anyone can help me to understand why the application doesn't work when facebook app is installed in my device?

Comment: Is it possible to see the logcat?  Also, make sure you're passing in the correct hashkey

Comment: The most likely cause of this is you haven't set up the correct key hash in your app settings. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/#create-app

Answer (score 0):

i think that key hash problem follow the code paste the hashcode generated in your app settings page.

```
    // Add code to print out the key hash
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.example.assessment", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:",
                    Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```